# Angular 'lazy' routing with parameters works in local but not in production

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Good afternoon,

I'm a Junior Developer, quite new with Angular, and I'm having some issues with the routing when the path contains parameters. I'm currently using Angular 7.

I have a component where the user can select and ID and two dates and then display data according to these. I also need to this component to display the data by taking the options from the parameters if there's any. I managed to do it without problems and it's working in local but once the app was deployed in the server it wasn't working.

The path I'm using is

> myUrl.com/myAPPname/diary/2/2018-12-20/2018-12-20

When adding parameters the browser tries to get the scripts from:

> myUrl.com/myAPPname/diary/2/2018-12-20/main.js
>
> myUrl.com/myAPPname/diary/2/2018-12-20/polyfill.js

instead of:

> myUrl.com/myAPPname/main.js
>
> myUrl.com/myAPPname/polyfill.js

This component is part of a module loaded with lazy loading from the main module. This is the routing of the module. As I said, it's working in local but it fails when the application is deployed in the server.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'diary', component: DiaryComponent },
            { path: 'diary/:id/:dateFrom/:dateTo', component: DiaryComponent }
        ]
    },
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi. what is the base href you have in your index.html at the root of your project? it should be something like <base href="/myAPPname/"> inside the <head> tag

Comment: The base href in the code is <base href="/"> but when the application is built and deployed 'build --configuration=des --base-href ./' it's used and as far as I know that overrides the base href in the index. Am I right? 
I don't have control over the server but I can notify it to see if that fixes the issue. Thanks for your answer :). I will tell if it works.

Comment: I think it is worth a try ;-)

Comment: Hi again, JavierFromMadrid. 
Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one? 
It worked!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base href you have in your index.html at the root of your project should be something like this:

```
<head>
    <base href="/myAPPname/">
</head>
```

It is telling Angular which is the root path for retrieveing compiled scripts and resources.

Comment: In my case the server that deploys the application used ' --base-href ./ ' so that overrided the tag in the index.html.
I ask to be changed to --base-href /myAPPname/ and it finally worked!.

Many thanks, JavierFromMadrid. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super experienced with Angular but looks like you defined the path with three parameters `:/id/:dateFrom/:dateTo` but your URL has only 2. i.e. `myUrl.com/myAPPname/diary/2018-12-20/2018-12-20`

You might need to pass the `:id` part as well. Anyhow here's [routing guide regarding parameters](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters) that could be useful.

Cheers & Good luck :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. There was a typo in my post (i missed the id parameter), I just corrected it.